# Digital PLL behaviour when signals start off at the same frequency but out of phase

Tags: pll

I am studying Digital PLL's.  I'm puzzled by what happens when the two input signals (input + feedback) start at the same frequency but at different phases.  As far as I can see the error signal from the phase detector will cause the VCO to change to a different frequency ( either larger or smaller than the input frequency, depending on which of the two input signals is leading). Assuming that the initial phase difference is quite large, does the feedback frequency immediately change to a substantially different frequency and then slowly converge back to the input frequency as the difference in phase of the two signals gets smaller ?

Comment: As I understand it - and I may be mistaken - if there is a *constant* difference in phase, then the error voltage also remains constant and there's no change in the output frequency. So the difference in phase is used to align the frequencies, not to align the phases. I'd be happy if someone more knowledgable would confirm or deny this though so also waiting for some answers!

Comment: I would say yes, it depends on the loop gain factor, large gain will minimize the phase offset and have a quick response, but it can reach the stability margin and become unstable.

Comment: @RogerRowland Not quite right - it's called a _Phase_ locked loop, because when it's in lock, the phases are synchronized. Most phase detectors don't themselves distinguish between out-of-phase and different frequencies.

Comment: Almost correct : but the feedback frequency doesn't "immediately" change, it changes according to the step response of the loop filter. You put DC (representing a constant phase error) into a low pass filter, its output will ramp towards that DC value, and the feedback frequency will follow.

Answer (score 1):

There will be an error voltage due to the phase error and, if the control loop uses an integrator then the frequency of the VCO will slightly increase to catch up to the correct phase of the reference signal.

Once it reaches the correct phase the phase error will be zero but the integrator (working from the error signal) will drive the VCO past the perfect phase point and what happens next is totally down to what other error processing mechanisms you have in place for instance: -

- The overshoot of phase is small and gradually, after a few cycles of oscillating around the desired set-point, the error become pretty close to zero.
- The "system" continues to oscillate with the average error being zero
- The system becomes unstable

Without knowledge of the other components I cannot say what will happen but, the intention, I suspect would be to settle down to a zero error (indistinguishable from noise).